# how to get the time average on sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have a table in **SQLite** with 3 columns **time, scramble and datetime.**

i need to calculate the average of the column **time** it has a format acording to the documentacion of **SQLite** about *date and time* data which is **00:00:00.000 %H%M%f**

if i use the **min** or **max** function

`select min(time) from records.` 
or
`select max(time) from records.`

returns a correct values.

but if i use

`select avg(time) from records.`

it returns **0.0**
i have read about it , the documentation of **AVG** function says dosnt have **TEXT** as valid
data format, i alrready do it programatically but i was wondering if exists a function or query for this.

TFYT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must use `strftime('%s', time)` to get the time as unix epoch (seconds since `1970-01-01`) and then multiply by 1000 and add the miliseconds.
The result is an integer and can be used to get the average.
This average is a float which must be divided by 1000 and cast to an integer so that `time()` function can be used to convert it back to `TIME`:

```
SELECT time(
          CAST(AVG(strftime('%s', time) * 1000 + SUBSTR(time, -3)) / 1000 AS INTEGER), 
         'unixepoch'
       )
FROM records
```

Actually you don't get more accuracy by using the milliseconds in the calculation, so get the average separately for the milliseconds and concatenate:

```
SELECT time(AVG(strftime('%s', time)), 'unixepoch') || '.' ||
       printf('%03d', AVG(SUBSTR(time, -3))) average_time
FROM records
```

For better accuracy try this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT AVG(strftime('%s', time) * 1000 + SUBSTR(time, -3)) avg_seconds
  FROM records
)
SELECT time(CAST(avg_seconds / 1000 AS INTEGER), 'unixepoch') 
       || '.' ||
       printf('%03d', ROUND(avg_seconds) % 1000) average_time
FROM cte
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d33f13cbd98ed07aa58c6142c79a5834).

Comment: ...its just what im looking for , but how i can display the milliseconds to?

Comment: i was working with you recomendations, apparently it works perfectly, but is not accurate enough :(

Comment: @diegomontiel for a more accurate result the code is more complicated. Try my 3d solution.